# Incorrect auto size column template on CSS Grid when jsf 2.1 generates an inputNumber-button xhtml

Tags: html, css, css-grid, jsf-2.2

I have create a jsf 2.1 page with the following content:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="grupodetalleCodprovincia"
 style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;">
 <p:inputNumber value="#{cc.attrs.sptiti28Controller.mensajeDto.cabecera.codprovincia}"
 style="width: 4ch;" id="detalleCodprovincia" styleClass="campoNumero"
 minValue="0" maxValue="99" decimalPlaces="0"
 readonly="#cc.attrs.sptiti28Controller.getSoloLectura('codprovincia')}" />
 <p:commandButton
  action="#{cc.attrs.sptiti28Controller.buscardetalleCodprovinciaClick()}"
  title="#{mensajes['SPTITI28.buscarCodprovincia']}"
  update="detalleCodprovincia" icon="pi pi-search" />
  <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.sptiti28Controller.mensajeDto.cabecera.provincia}"
   id="detalleProvincia" styleClass="campoTexto" style="width: 52ch;"
   converter="trimConverter" maxlength="50" readonly="true" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

that generates roughly the following html on browser (simplified for understanding the problem)

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;">
    <span style="display: block; width: 4ch;">
        <input type="text" style="text-align: right; width: 100%;"  value="20">
        <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
    </span>
    <button style="width: 20px;"/>
    <input type="text" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; margin-left: 4px; width: 52ch;"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

The html produces a mistake, at least on chrome version 106.0.5249.103, and position the button overlapping the first input.

[Execution on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzW2T.png)

This behaviour doesn't show if the input changes to inputText instead of an inputNumber.

Anyone knows if there is a hack to allow the correct calculation of the column width? Anyone can explain me if there is any problem on my definition?

Best regards,